# Azure data factory pipeline is missing some preparties from api response

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, microsoft-dynamics

I have created ADF pipeline, added a copy data activity and in source connection I have created linked service to Dynamics AX and added as source.
Now issue is while loading data from Dynamics AX the pipeline is missing some of the response properties.
ex. I am calling Dynamics AX api in browser getting 10 properties in response like {Id:1, name:'xyz', IsActive:1,.....so on} but in adf pipeline not getting all of these properties getting only ~8 properties like{Id:1, name:'xyz',.....so on}, some of the properties are missing for example IsActive.